# Passing variable from one class to a view of a different class

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm having a bit of trouble passing the variable score, that is a variable in my Evaluation class, that is initialized here in my [httpPost]ifstatements(Evaluation model) method in my Quiz controller to a view belonging to a different controller of a different class. When the score is greater than zero, i.e i answer at least one question correct, I am brought to the results view and the score is shown to me. But im having trouble printing that score out in another view called Index that is part of my index method in my LEADERBOARD controller of the LEADERBOARD class

**Quiz Controller**

```
public ActionResult ifStatement()
{
    var evalVM = new Evaluation();

    //the below is hardcoded for DEMO. you may get the data from some  
    //other place and set the questions and answers

    var q1 = new Question { ID = 1, QuestionText = "1. Which of the following shows the correct syntax for an if statement?" };
    q1.Answers.Add(new Answer { ID = 12, AnswerText = "a. if expression" });
    q1.Answers.Add(new Answer { ID = 13, AnswerText = "b. if { expression }" });
    q1.Answers.Add(new Answer { ID = 14, AnswerText = "c. if ( expression ){}" });
    q1.Answers.Add(new Answer { ID = 15, AnswerText = "d. expression if" });
    evalVM.Questions.Add(q1);

    return View(evalVM);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ifStatement(Evaluation model)
{
    int score = 0;

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        using (UsersContext db = new UsersContext())
        {
            foreach (var q in model.Questions)
            {
                var qId = q.ID;

                List<string> listSelectedAnswer = new List<string>();

                listSelectedAnswer.Add("14");
                listSelectedAnswer.Add("19");
                listSelectedAnswer.Add("22");
                listSelectedAnswer.Add("25");
                listSelectedAnswer.Add("28");
                listSelectedAnswer.Add("33");

                foreach (string answer in listSelectedAnswer)
                {
                    foreach (var answer2 in model.Questions)
                    {
                        if (answer == answer2.SelectedAnswer)
                        {
                            score = score + 3;
                        }
                    }
                }

                model.Score = score;

                ViewBag.score = model.Score;

                if (score > 0)
                {
                    return View("results");
                }
                else
                {
                    //score = 0;
                    //return Content("Please check all answers have been submitted!");
                    return Content("Error, please ensure all questions have been answered. You may use the back button to continue the Quiz."); //PRG Pattern
                }
            }
        }
    }

    model.setScore(score);
    return View("ThankYou");
}
```

**Leaderboard Controller**

```
public class LeaderboardController : Controller
{
    UsersContext db = new UsersContext();
    //
    // GET: /Leaderboard/

    TutorialEntities t = new TutorialEntities();
    Evaluation e = new Evaluation();

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        // Evaluation ev = new Evaluation();
        // var tutorial = t.Evaluations.ToList();
        //ViewBag.Scores = t.Evaluations.Select(a => a.Score).ToList();
        //ViewBag.Scores = e.getScore();
        //ViewBag.Score = e.getScore();

        ViewBag.Users = db.UserProfiles.ToList();
        ViewBag.Scores = t.Evaluations.ToList();
        return View();

    }
}
```

**Index View**

```
<h2>Leaderboard</h2>

@foreach (var item2 in ViewBag.Users)
{
    <p>
        Score: @ViewBag.Score
    </p>
}

@foreach (var item in ViewBag.Users)
{
    <p>
        UserID: @item.UserId
        <br />
        UserName: @item.UserName
        <br />
    </p>
}
```

All that shows on the page when i go this view is the name of the people who are registered on my website and their id but score is blank! I cant seem to get my head around it i have tried numerous ways but it seems it cant see the score that is being initialised in the ifstatement method

Answer (score 0):

Your controller sets viewbag.scores, however your view is trying to access viewbag.score?

Comment: thanks for the reply, i changed it to this

    @foreach(var item2 in ViewBag.Score) 
    {
    <p>
   Score: @ViewBag.Score
        </p>
    }
   
    @foreach(var item in ViewBag.Users)
    {
        
       
   
           <p> UserID: item.UserId
       <br />
             UserName: item.UserName
               <br />
               </p>
    }

but still all that displays in the view is userId and USerName, even the actual word "Score" doesnt display